# struct member and boost::hana::filter

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++17, boost-hana

Faced typical novice problem with constexpr modifier in modern c++.

Am I right that there's no way to write such code even in c++17 (cause of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-appendix-constexpr)?

And one must use "value as a type" idiom (use different types for Open and Closed files in this example)?

```
#include <boost/hana/filter.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

enum class State {
  Open, Closed
};

struct File {
  constexpr File(State state) : state_(state) {}

  constexpr State state() const { return state_; }

  const State state_;
};

constexpr auto files = hana::make_tuple(File(State::Closed), File(State::Open));
constexpr auto filtered = hana::filter(files, [](const auto& file) {
  return file.state() == State::Open;
});

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what the purpose of that code would be.

Comment: I have constexpr tuple with some structures and I want to get some subset of them depends on their member field in compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lambda that you pass to `hana::filter`, you have two problems:

1. The `file` parameter is not constexpr
2. The return value is not a compile-time `IntegralConstant` convertible to `bool` as is required by `hana::filter`.

One way to keep your tuple elements constexpr in any context is to wrap them in constexpr lambdas (added in C++17).

The following code addresses both issues:

```
constexpr auto files = hana::make_tuple(
  []{ return File(State::Closed); }
, []{ return File(State::Open); }
);

constexpr auto filtered = hana::filter(files, [](auto file) {
  return hana::bool_c<file().state() == State::Open>;
});
```

Comment: That's awesome and completely unintuitive: you can't pass variable, but you can pass lambda which returns this var. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to encode the `State` as part of `File`'s type:

```
template <State TState>
struct File 
{
    constexpr State state() const { return TState; }
};
```

Then, you need to return a compile-time friendly boolean from your filtering function:

```
constexpr auto files = hana::make_tuple(File<State::Closed>{}, File<State::Open>{});
constexpr auto filtered = hana::filter(files, [](const auto& file) 
{
    return hana::bool_c<decltype(file){}.state() == State::Open>;
});
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q82RJZDhw965MTtP)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean in "value as a type". That's sad, if there's only option :(

Comment: @yarr: do you need run-time or compile-time computations?

Comment: Compile-time only.